# PR curve and confusion matrix members for multiclass and multilabel classification problems

Tags: machine-learning, multi-class, multilabel, spark-mllib

I am looking for any libraries which provide out of box support for calculating PR curve and the confusion matrix items(not just count but the items which contributed to the count as well) for multiclass and multilabel classification solutions.

I have gone through the APIs on spark mllib [documentations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html). The PR curve is only supported for the binary classification usecases and not for multiclass or multilabel classification usecases. Confusion matrix is supported for all three usecases, but it doesn't seem to support getting the members contributing to it.would like to know if there is some library, which supports this. If not, I would write something for my own usage.

A solution on my end would be to model a spark job to calculate that, but I would rather not do that, if there is something out there already.

Please let me know, if further information is required.
Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks,
Sachi